# Why isn't my hook modifier centered to my selected EMPTY? Blender API

Tags: python, modifiers, lattice

I am attaching my EMPTY to my lattice vertices but it is attaching to the center of my lattice. I tried to set the center of my `hook modifier` to my EMPTY location but instead it shows that it is attached somewhere off screen. How can I set the center of my `hook modifier` to the center of my EMPTY?

```
for em in collection.objects:
    if em.type == "EMPTY":
        bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = lattice_ob
        lattice_ob.select_set(True)
        em.select_set(True)
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
        
        
        hookmod = lattice_ob.modifiers.new(f"Hook-{em.name}", 'HOOK')
        hookmod.falloff_radius = .5
        hookmod.falloff_type = 'SMOOTH'
        hookmod.center = (em.location.x, em.location.y, em.location.z)
        hookmod.vertex_indices_set(range(0, lat_total_verts))
        
        hookmod.object = em
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action = 'DESELECT')
```

[image]

Comment: Since no operators are involved above, could ditch the active object and mode setting. May need to update depsgraph or viewlayer in loop.

Answer (score 0):

The hook is based on the lattice coordinates which range from `(-0.5,-0.5,-0.5)` to `(0.5,0.5,0.5)` so to set the hook to the EMPTY location divide the EMPTY location by the lattice size and subtract 0.5:

```
lattx, latty, lattz = 224, 352, 224

dx = (em.location.x / lattx) - .5
dy = (em.location.y / latty) - .5
dz = (em.location.z / lattz) - .5

hookmod.center = dx, dy, dz
```

Answer (score 0):

**In the local space of the lattice.**

Somewhat speculative, if you have object transforms on your empty and lattice will need to put the empty location into the object space of the lattice.  Otherwise will get undesirable results. eg if empty at (1, 1, 1) and if the lattice has scale of 10 then that as a local coordinate of lattice is globally (10, 10, 10), potentially raising the issue outlined in question.

The empties global location is

```
global_loc = mt.matrix_world.translation
```

To put this global coordinate into the local space of the lattice

```
mwi = lattice_obj.matrix_world.inverted()
local_co = mwi @ global_loc
```

and use this to set the the modifier center.

*Note the method in your answer an example of the linear algebra, dividing by dimension is scale inverse, however will (likely) fail when objects have rotation / parent / constraint*